# Ajax success call function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have my ajax request and on success method I am trying to call another function but seems its not working. there is no error on console.

I am getting success message and all other calls after this function are also working.

here is my ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/tracking/insertrating',
    type: 'post',
    cache:false,
    data: {waybill:waybill,rating:rating,captainId:captainId},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){

        $('.comments').hide();
        $('.submitrating').hide();
        $('.rating').barrating({
            theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
            hoverState: false,
            readonly: true,
        });

    }
});
```

This function is not calling and has not effect. same function call working before ajax request.

```
$('.rating').barrating({
    theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
    hoverState: false,
    readonly: true,
});
```

Comment: From where you are calling another function?

Comment: updated my question. in success method i am calling .barrating jquery plugin function.

Comment: do you have any elements with the class "rating" in your page? We can't see your HTML. P.S. It's hard to see how the ajax part is relevant to this issue.

Comment: yes i do have rating class. and same function is working before ajax call but not on success call. @ADyson

Comment: ajax itself shouldn't make any difference to that as far as I can see. It would only be a problem if that HTML had perhaps been removed in the meantime, or if it didn't yet exist in the DOM when the "success" callback runs.

Comment: no its not removed. @ADyson. i am just trying to set different parameters to this function you see hover and click parameters. on success i am trying to set different parameters.

Comment: What options did you use when it worked? And where is the documentation for this plugin located please? So we can see what the possibilities are. And where is the code for it? or can you make a runnable demo (e.g. JSFiddle or StackSnippet) so we can try it out?

Comment: `readonly: true,` There is an additional `,` .

Comment: @SumeshTG JS won't complain about that generally. OP already states there are no console errors

Comment: Have you tried destroying `$('.rating').barrating('deestroy')` the element before recreating it? Here's the link I found: http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/

Comment: @Morgs no i havn't will give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.rating').barrating('destroy');
```

This worked for me. Thank you all for helping out here.

Answer (score 1):

Your AJAX post is not replacing existing content (at least from the code sample above), so if `.rating` elements are already registered, you cannot call

```
$('.rating').barrating({ settings })
```

again because that will try to re-register the control a second time, when it is already registered.  You would want to selectively target any new content to register the control for.  If your code is trying to register the plugin/widget twice, that might be a reason why it isn't working.

EDIT: You could also destroy and recreate the plugin through the API or if the plugin supports a refresh method of sorts (check the docs), there may be a method to call to refresh the plugin for the elements it is bound to.

Comment: I think he's trying to recreate the same element with new content that's returned from the AJax call. So I guess first have to destroy and recreate the element. Just like what you would do with most plugins...

Comment: @Morgs Yeah, it sounded like on load it registers initially and I wasn't sure if the intent of this call was to reload the UI, or call the plugin on newly created elements (assuming the AJAX call was to refresh part of the UI and that code wasn't included).

Answer (score -3):

This occurs because the AJAX is Asynchronous and success function will execute only after receiving response , so "async : false " will make the code wait for the success function to execute

```
  $.ajax({

                            url: '/tracking/insertrating',
                            type: 'post',
                            async:false,/*add this*/                                cache:false,
                            data: {waybill:waybill,rating:rating,captainId:captainId},
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(data){

                              $('.comments').hide();
                              $('.submitrating').hide();
                               $('.rating').barrating({
                theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
                hoverState: false,
                readonly: true,
                });

                            }
                        });
```

In some versions of jquery async false will not work , in that case you need to bind the function to some other event

Comment: `async:false` is deprecated in most browsers now, due to the fact it creates a terrible user experience (the browser UI is locked during the request) especially on longer-running or frequent requests. Since it's deprecated it will generate browser warnings now, and in future you can expect it to stop working entirely. I would not recommend such an approach. AJAX is intended to be async, and in any case the synchronous-ness of the AJAX has absolutely no bearing on the situation in this question. OP is already handling the output correctly in the "success" callback.

Comment: Your statement _""async : false " will make the code wait for the success function to execute"_ is completely wrong. $.ajax() will _always_ wait for the request to complete before executing the "success" callback - that's the whole purpose of it. Your statement is worrying and makes me think that you do not properly understand AJAX.

Comment: Sure , What I mentioned is time lapse between jquery and $.ajax . $ajax will create a separate thread and the things are sent and  response is taken at a time parallel to the js/jquery code below the ajax call

Comment: "response is taken at a time parallel to the js/jquery code below the ajax call"...that's true, but in this question there is no code below the ajax - everything is in "success", including the code which the OP is saying is the problem. That's why your answer is not relevant. And also as I mentioned you should in any case not encourage the use of code which is already deprecated.